# Setting dropdown in webpage but with no php

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use hover property for dropdown but I do not understand
how to use lab1, lab 2, lab 3 ,lab4, lab 5 when they are not defined.

I know how to use hover property but for multiple ul and li is little hard for me to get it.

Dropdowns are not coming down. All my other css properties are fine, I just need help in dropdown property. Any idea?

```css
body {
  font: 1.2em Verdana, sans-serif;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

#header,
#footer {
  background-color: #aaa;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

#content h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#wrapper {
  //background-color: hsl(200, 75%, 40%);
}

#content {
  border-left: 8em solid hsl(200, 75%, 40%);
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: hsl(200, 75%, 60%);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#leftnav {
  float: left;
  width: 8em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#leftnav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

#leftnav li {
  color: white;
  background-color: hsl(200, 75%, 30%);
  padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 1px 0;
}

#leftnav li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

#leftnav li:first-child {
  border-top: none;
}

#leftnav li:hover {
  text-decoration: red;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>Lab 1
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"> Basic XHTML </a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Lab 2
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"> Nesting Errors - Fixed </a> </li>
        <li><a href="#"> Block and Inline Elements </a> </li>
        <li><a href="#"> List of Links </a> </li>
        <li><a href="#"> Lab Index </a> </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Lab 3
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"> Merging Table Cells </a> </li>
        <li><a href="#"> Common Page Layout </a> </li>
        <li><a href="#"> XHTML Vocabulary </a> </li>
        <li><a href="#"> Vocabulary with Examples </a> </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Lab 4
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"> CSS - HTML Selectors </a> </li>
        <li><a href="#"> CSS - More Selectors </a> </li>
        <li><a href="#"> Table Styling </a> </li>
        <li><a href="#"> CS - Descendant Selectors </a> </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Lab 5
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"> Body Style</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#"> Inheriting Colours </a> </li>
        <li><a href="#"> Structuring Text </a> </li>
        <li><a href="#"> Another Lab Index </a> </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <p class="clearboth"></p>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not use `select` tag if you want a dropdown list?

Comment: Add relevant css too.

Comment: select tag? how can i use that. any example? carl jan

Comment: Hey Abhishek .I attached the css file too.

Comment: @S.agnihotri, could you please be more specific. What do you mean by 'dropdowns' are not coming down? Which part of your content is a 'dropdown'? What do you mean by 'not coming down'? Are you looking for a traditional menu where the 2nd ul is hidden until you hover over the li of the first ul?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand correctly, you are making a navbar and try to place the dropdown of the child element when people hover the parent element? The idea of ul-li-ul is that when you hover over a li element, the consequence ul will show up, so you don't actually need to define which lab is going to open which one.

```css
#nav li ul{
        display: none;
    }
#nav li:hover>ul{
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        margin-left: 50px;
    }
```

```html
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Basic XHTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">LAB 2</a>
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#"> Nesting Errors - Fixed </a> </li>
        <li><a href="#"> Block and Inline Elements </a> </li>
        <li><a href="#"> List of Links </a> </li>
        <li><a href="#"> Lab Index </a> </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">LAB 3</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"> Merging Table Cells </a> </li>
        <li><a href="#"> Common Page Layout </a> </li>
        <li><a href="#"> XHTML Vocabulary </a> </li>
        <li><a href="#"> Vocabulary with Examples </a> </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You may use select tag. Example:

```html
<select>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

> The `<select>` element is used to create a drop-down list.
>
> The `<option>` tags inside the `<select>` element define the available options in the list.

Code taken at: [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp)

Comment: well! that a pretty good information. thanks i appreciate. but i'm trying to use css keeping body content as it is

Comment: @S.agnihotri This is what I mean by using the `select` tag instead. But it seems you don't like it

Comment: @CarlJan i really appreciate your help. well i'm new to it. little experiment is acceptable. i going to write in select now. thanks